# Как расположить элементы за container?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

дайте пожалуйста совет. Можно ли как-то расположить элементы за container

```
.container {
  max-widht: 1440px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

или же всё таки лучше убрать полностью container, но тогда другой вопрос, можно ли будет адаптировать такой сайт (без container)?

Прошу прощения, если мой вопрос покажется вам глупым, я просто новичок в этой сфере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="banner">
   <h1 class="banner-text">Новый сайт -<br>глоток свежего<br>воздуха для<br>вашего бизнеса</h1>
</div>
```

```
.banner {
    width: 100vw;
    margin: -1px;
    background-image: url(/img/Banner.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    &-text {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 137px;
        padding-bottom: 180px;
        padding-left: 185px;
        color: #545454;
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}

.product {
    padding-bottom: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    &-text {
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #545454;
    }
}
```

Comment: Речь о изображении на фоне?

Comment: Да, изображение должно выходить из контейнера, при этом текст должен должен оставаться в контейнере.

Comment: сделай изображение абсолютом. Добавь к секции отступы сверху и снизу, добавь position: relative. 

демка: https://jsfiddle.net/uhygv8fb/5/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня получилось не совсем так, как должно было: (https://imgur.com/a/vepIkgc). Код прикрепил выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свойство `background-size`, чтобы подогнать картинку. Значение `cover` будет масштабировать фоновое изображение по меньшей стороне (то есть картинка будет обрезаться), а `contain` - по большей (то есть сверху-снизу или слева-справа будет пустое место). Есть и другие значения, так что советую ознакомиться с этим свойством по-подробнее.

Для выравнивания фонового изображения используйте `background-position`.